# Can't properly start Service in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, service, android-mediaplayer

I develope small MediaPlayer app which contains one activity with several fragments. Idea is that my PlayerFragment displays in MainActivity, recieving data from other fragment and starting MusicService. Problem begins when it passes song position to MusicService and try to start it in that fragment.
When I run the code, onStartCommand method in MusicService don't execute, though onCreate and onBind working properly.

PlayerFragment

```
public class PlayerFragment extends Fragment implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener,
        ServiceConnection {
  private int position = 0;

  @Nullable
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_player, container, false);
   return view;
  }

 @Override
 public void onResume() {
     Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MusicService.class);
     getContext().bindService(intent, this, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
 }

@Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        MusicService.MyBinder myBinder = (MusicService.MyBinder)service;
        musicService = myBinder.getService();
        fetchFromBundle();
 }

  private void fetchFromBundle() {
   position = getArguments().getInt("position");
   Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MusicService.class);
   intent.putExtra("servicePosition", position);
   getContext().startService(intent);
 }

}
```

MusicService

```
public class MusicService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {
    IBinder mBinder = new MyBinder();
    int position = -1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        System.out.println(">>> MusicService create");
        super.onCreate();

    }

   @Nullable
   @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        System.out.println(">>> MusicService bind");
        return mBinder;
    }

   @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        int myPosition = intent.getIntExtra("servicePosition", -1);
        System.out.println(">>> MusicService start myPosition: " + myPosition);
        if(myPosition != -1){
            playMedia(myPosition);
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }


    public class MyBinder extends Binder {
        public MusicService getService(){
            return MusicService.this;
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest

```
<service android:name=".Services.MusicService" android:enabled="true" />
```

Comment: If you're using a binder, why are you using an Intent to send commands?  The point of a Binder is to be able to use normal Java function calls to pass commands to an existing service.

Comment: Intent used for starting MusicService

Comment: Yes, but why?  If you bind it, you don't need to start it.  And if you're trying to send different parameters, the right way to do it is to create an interface in the binder, not to send a start service.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that way.